# How could I find specific attribute in XML file multiple time?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document :

```
<Results>
  <ResultSet "nothing special" Description="More of nothing" type="system">
    <Results1>
      <time>
        <Body type="system" datatype="int"></Body>
        <att2 type="session" datatype="float"></att2>
      </Result>
      <Result>
        <ID type="system" datatype="int"></ID>
        <Stuff type="session" datatype="float"></Stuff>
      </Result>
      <Result>
        <att1 type="system" datatype="int"></att1>
        <att2 type="session" datatype="int"></att2>
      </Result>
    </Results1>
    <Results2>
      <time>
        <att1 type="session" datatype="int"></att1>
        <att2 type="system" datatype="float"></att2>
      </Result>
      <Result>
        <ID type="system" datatype="float"></ID>
      </Result>
    </Results2>
  </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

I would like to get the path for each `type = "session"` in the document in a list using C#. For the moment, I have a function to get the path `XPath`. But I have absolutely no idea about how to search in ALL the XML no matter the node.

I'm using LINQ to XML, .NET framework 3.5 and this is what I have for the moment :

```
    List<string> pathList = new List<string>(); 
    IEnumerable<XElement> path =
        from element in doc.Elements(/*I don't know*/)
        where (string)element.Attribute("type") == "session"
        select element;

    foreach (XElement element in path)
    {
        pathList.Add(getPath(element));
    }
```

Comment: Your XML is not Well formed.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yeah, you are right. The one in my question isn't the real one and it took around 2 minutes to make a more general case... and I miss some important things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doc.Descendants()` to get all descendant elements:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> path =
    from element in doc.Descendants()
    where (string)element.Attribute("type") == "session"
    select element;
```

Comment: Do you know what would it be in `XMLDocument`?

Answer (score 2):

**Your XML does not have a single XML attribute.** All you have is elements with text content.

Did you mean:

```
<Results>
  <ResultSet "nothing special" Description="More of nothing" type="system">
    <Results1>
      <time>
        <Body type="system" datatype="int"></Body>
        <att2 type="session" datatype="float"></att2>
      </Result>
      <Result>
        <ID type="system" datatype="int"></ID>
        <Stuff type="session" datatype="float"></Stuff>
      </Result>
      <Result>
        <att1 type="system" datatype="int"></att1>
        <att2 type="session" datatype="int"></att2>
      </Result>
    </Results1>
    <Results2>
      <time>
        <att1 type="session" datatype="int"></att1>
        <att2 type="system" datatype="float"></att2>
      </Result>
      <Result>
        <ID type="system" datatype="float"></ID>
      </Result>
    </Results2>
  </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

??

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The one in my question isn't the real one and it took around 2 minutes to make a more general case... and I miss some important things.